# Face all outside edges at once

Tags: modifiers, faces

I made a model using the difference boolean modifier. It is the correct shape, but all of the outside faces are open now, is there a way to face all of them at once? The geometry is a bit funky so I am not sure how hard it will be.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, big novice with blender just trying to figure some stuff out.

Comment: Do you want all those internal faces?

Comment: I am trying to make something to 3D print, so I think so. I basically need a watertight object once I do the boolean difference.